# Bash: Swap the two last arguments of the current command line

Tags: bash, command-line, readline

Just saw a tip [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10412/swap-the-two-last-arguments-of-the-current-command-line), but I'm not able to make it fully working.

Here is how it plays out:

- type `echo abc def`, then hit enter.
- key in `<Up><Alt-T>`, that `echo abc def` will becomes `echo def abc`

However, I'm not able to make what the above tip *fully* works. I.e., `echo /long/path/to/dir_a /very/long/path/to/dir_b` were never get properly swapped -- instead I get `echo /long/path/to/dir_a /very/long/path/to/b_dir`. The comments below the tip get similar results too.

Anyone knows how the tip author made it worked?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187600/how-do-i-swap-the-two-last-command-line-arguments

Comment: @tripleee, please don't just mark it duplicate because the title is the same -- look at the solution there. I agree with your comment _"The real solution is to modify the word separator"_ but that solution is not there in your referenced Cross-site "duplicate", https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187600/. Thanks

Comment: I have not marked this as a duplicate, and indeed couldn't. I have simply left a comment.

Comment: For that discussion, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78990/what-are-the-readline-word-separators - it looks like you can't change the delimiter cbut Bash 4 brings some relief in the form of additional readline commands).

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357191/changing-word-delimiters-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

`Alt+t` is swapping a word under cursor with the previous word. Since '/' is treated as word separator you get the weird behavior.

Try doing `Ctrl+e` `Escape+t`.

Comment: Esc-t and Alt-t both do the same thing for me (as you would expect). The real solution is to modify the word separator or try a different approach which operates on tokens rather than on "words".

Answer (score 0):

vi mode can do this:

```
set -o vi
```

Then stay cursor at the first word (e. g. Esc-2w) and press hdeep.